# Rails SQL query with % Wildcards works in SQLite but not PostgreSQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, wildcard

I have a query I'm using for a search with :conditions like this:

```
:conditions => ['family_name LIKE ? OR given_name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%"]
```

The query works fine locally on SQLite, but when I push to Heroku on PostgreSQL, only the first % works for both family_name and given_name. In other words, it will match a keyword that occurs at the end of a word but not the beginning or middle.

**Example:**
There is an existing record with :family_name => "Washington" and :given_name => "George"

A search for "ington" or "rge" will retrieve this record. A search for "Wash" or "Geo" will not.

I'm a new user and am pretty new to rails. Thanks in advance for your help.

---

**Solution**

Related threads:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203399/how-do-you-write-a-case-insensitive-query-for-both-mysql-and-postgres)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983687/how-to-do-case-insensitive-order-in-rails-with-postgresql)

Here's the fix I am using:

```
:conditions => ['LOWER(family_name) LIKE ? OR LOWER(given_name) LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search].downcase}%", "%#{params[:search].downcase}%"]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`LIKE` is a case-sensitive operator in Postgres. For case-insensitive pattern matching use `ILIKE` or [other standard methods](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-matching.html).

Comment: The query being case-sensitive never even crossed my mind. Thanks so much.

I ended up setting everything to lowercase in the query because it's compatible with both types of databases.

Edit: Added final code to the question.