# Wildcard search not working on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have the following method in my model:

```
 #find all the manufacturers names and ids or those matching a search string
  def self.find_all(manufacturer="")
       m_name =  manufacturer.gsub(" ", '%') if manufacturer
    find(:all, :select => 'id, name', :order => "name", :conditions => ["name like ?", "%#{m_name.capitalize}%"])
  end
```

This works perfectly on my local machine, but when I put it on Heroku it works less well: if I do a search and enter more than one word it won't return any values.

What is different about Heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it has something to do with the "Like" statement. mysql and heroku's postgresql sometime needs code modifications when switching between the two.

maybe try

```
"name ILIKE ?"
```

also checkout this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161108/rails-sql-query-with-wildcards-works-in-sqlite-but-not-postgresql). Always best to use same database in development and production.

Comment: I did not know about the ilike sql statement for postgresql. Once I used that it all worked. Thanks HIshalv

Comment: @chell glad to help, i ran into a similar problem some time back. Also try checking out this page <a href="http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database#common_issues_migrating_to_postgresql">here</a>

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts.
Firstly, try running it in production mode locally:

```
rails server -e production
```

Also it may be that your remote database is very different to your local one.

Make sure you have done

```
rake db:migrate
```

You could optionally also do

```
rake db:push
```

(see http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/taps for more info)

Comment: Thanks David for your answer. You are right. I was running MYSQL locally and its  Postgres on HEROKU.